# Apply cutplanes to heatmaps

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a model with a few heatmaps and I'm trying to make the cutplanes work with them, but currently not achieving it.

I searched on the DataViz api documentation and I didn't found any information on it, even though I've noticed that on the DataViz reference app you can select by floor and it looks like a cutplane. Any idea?

[image: Demo]

Comment: Unfortunately, viewer's overlays (overlay scenes) don't support cut planes. The heatmaps are made by viewer's overlays, so that's it. But I'm checking with our engineering team for insights. Will get back to you A.S.A.P.

Comment: It's supported now. Please have a try. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Good News! Heatmap gets cut planes supported now. (tested with v7.58)

[image]

=====

I got the confirmation from our engineering team. Unfortunately, the cut planes aren't implemented for the Heatmaps now, so we logged a wishlist item, `LMV-6409`, to add this support. You're welcome to track updates via sending an email to forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com quoting this wishlist item id.